# php.ini variables for file upload size

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

In my apache server, I have 3 directories for php.ini `7.2`, `7.4`, and `8.0`. At first I edited php.ini inside `7.4/fpm/php.ini` but its not working. It throws me error saying

```
Illuminate\\Http\\Exceptions\\PostTooLargeException
```

so I edited all php.ini inside every php versions. and it still gives me  the same error.
`upload_max_filesize=500M`
`post_max_size=500M`
`memory_limit=500M`

As for the Laravel Controller.

I have a validator set like this: I set it to `400MB` just to make sure.

```
$validator = $request->validate([
            'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,ogx,oga,ogv,ogg,webm|max:400000'
        ]);
```

Yet it still gives me error.

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Call phpinfo, and check which php.ini gets actually used.

Comment: how do I actually do that? sorry newbie

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php